# A knob that can be turned by hand, have the position read, and turned by software to another position?

Tags: arduino-uno, hardware

I'd like to be able to change variables on the Arduino by adjusting a set of knobs.  When I get to a desirable setting I'd like to be able to save those settings on the Arduino... and then I'd like to be able to load those settings back, and have the knobs turn themselves back to the correct positions.  Specifically I'm thinking of using this with a synthesizer.

I understand how to do all of this, except, I don't know if there are knobs that allow this type of behavior.

Comment: I think one of my amplifiers had something like that. Google "motorized potentiometer". There seem to be a few on eBay, amongst other places.

Comment: You might also consider using KY-040 rotary-encoders, with no cal marks on the knobs.  When you reload settings, just change all the current-position counts to match the reloaded values.  I can add this as an answer with a little more detail if you like.

Comment: Thanks Nick.  Looks like theres one here: http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/ALPS/RK16812MG099/?qs=uOLQ569YubvkId4TDNOKXQ%3D%3D

Answer (score 2):

If you attach a knob to the [Analog Feedback Micro Servo](https://www.adafruit.com/products/1450), either directly or via gears, then you can use the pot output to measure the current position and use the normal servo control protocol to turn it under software control.

Answer (score 2):

Not a knob, but depending on your application, would a [motorized slider like this be applicable](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10976)?

You would read it just as you would a potentiality, and you have a motor that you can use to drive it to a specific position when you make a change in your software.

As for knobs, I have seen very few if any *motorized knobs*. What I would recommend here would be a continuous rotation encoder so that the position of the knob actually doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, just add an LED/LCD display on top of each knob (or have a larger LCD showing info for all the knobs) to show the value.
Then you can have the knobs implemented with an optical rotary encoder.

Each knob is unmarked and doesn't need to be reset.

This solution doesn't put any mechanical part under strain.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't get a motorised potentiometer could you use a rotary encoder, a motor, a shaft and some cogs.  Press the shaft and rotate manually then release and it disengages the manual cog and moves back to the motor cog.